# Change Win32 Window Style

Tags: winapi

Is there a win32 function to change the style of a window after it has been created? I would like to change the style flags that are specified in `CreateWindowEx`. Specifically, I would like to convert a standard window to a window with no border and no resize.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think [`SetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898(VS.85).aspx) should do that. Note that you need to call `SetWindowPos` afterwards if you changed the border style, as pointed out in the remarks.

Some styles only take effect during window creation and so can not be set by this call. MSDN normally calls out styles that CAN be set afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

```
HWND windowHandle = FindWindow(NULL, L"Various tests");
    SetWindowLongPtr(windowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_SYSMENU); //3d argument=style
    SetWindowPos(windowHandle, HWND_TOPMOST, 100, 100, Width, Height, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

did it for me :D

Answer (score 1):

You should try this window style in the createwindowex or SetWindowLongPtr: `WS_POPUPWINDOW|WS_TABSTOP |WS_VISIBLE`

Comment: If you change a windows properties after it is created, you will ned to use SetWindowPos with the correct flags for the update to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

The way i solved it by using combination of **SetWindowPos** and **ShowWindow** methods.

**NOTE** that calling **showWindow** is must here otherwise it won't work.

Here is the full ***source code*** below. Just call **setConsoleWindowStyle()** method and set new window style.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

LONG_PTR setConsoleWindowStyle(INT,LONG_PTR);

int main()
{
    LONG_PTR new_style =  WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL;
    setConsoleWindowStyle(GWL_STYLE,new_style);
    return 0;
}

LONG_PTR setConsoleWindowStyle(INT n_index,LONG_PTR new_style)
{
 /*The function does not clear the last error information. if last value was zero.*/
 SetLastError(NO_ERROR);        

 HWND hwnd_console = GetConsoleWindow();
 LONG_PTR style_ptr = SetWindowLongPtr(hwnd_console,n_index,new_style);
 SetWindowPos(hwnd_console,0,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_DRAWFRAME);

 //show window after updating
 ShowWindow(hwnd_console,SW_SHOW);

 return style_ptr;  
}
```

Comment: `ShowWindow` is not a must, pass `SWP_SHOWWINDOW` to `SetWindowPos` instead.

Answer (score 0):

SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE, newStyle);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);

Comment: Would be helpful if you explained why this worked rather than just posting the function