# WinApi - change Window Style

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to change my windo style during runtime. I use this code

```
if (this->fullscreen)
{
    this->style = WS_POPUP|WS_VISIBLE;
}
else 
{
    this->style = WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_SYSMENU|WS_VISIBLE;
}

    SetWindowLongPtr(this->mainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, this->style);

        SetWindowPos(this->mainWindowHandle, 
                HWND_TOP, 
                0, 
                0,
                0,    //New Width
                0, //New Height, 
            SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
```

But it has no effect... and window is still without border (WS_POPUP)...

Comment: Full code here: http://pastie.org/1552396

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Just curious.

Comment: check out solved answer here [Change Win32 Window Style
 solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49886801/6219626)

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can't modify those particular styles after the window is created. If you're going to try to anyway, it also says that WS_SYSMENU requires WS_CAPTION.

Comment: +1.  You'll probably need separate windows for full-screen and windowed modes and switch between them as needed (by enabling the right window and making it visible and doing the reverse to the other).

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `SetWindowPos` with the flag `SWP_DRAWFRAME` and see if it helps.

Comment: No help.. SWP_DRAWFRAME is define for SWP_FRAMECHANGED (or the othew way)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use [CWnd::ModifyStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xhz2t1c.aspx). Have a look at example [here](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=352963)

Answer (score 0):

You might save the current pos and size from the actual window. Then destroy it an create an new window with the new style, previous pos and size.

Comment: You don't need to destroy and re-create to do this.

Comment: some window stile can not  be changed at runtime, so the this step is need!.