# WinApi - How To Modify Console Window?

Tags: winapi, console, window

I want my **console window** to be modified. I got the handle. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285860/change-win32-window-style) helps to change it. But how can I

- remove close button
- remove maximize button
- remove icon
- disable resizing

?

```
// C# syntax
StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(260);
IntPtr window = FindWindow(null, buffer.ToString(0, GetConsoleTitle(buffer, buffer.Capacity)));

uint a = (uint)((WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION) & (~WS_ICONIC));
SetWindowLongPtr(window, -16, new IntPtr(a)); // GWL_STYLE = -16
```

For some reason the window is broken after this call. I can't move it with the mouse anymore and all clicks go through it to other windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You removed **all** the window styles, and added back just `WS_BORDER` and `WS_CAPTION`. What you should do is:

1. Read the current window style with a call to `GetWindowLongPtr`.
2. Perform bitwise `AND` with the bitwise negation of the styles you want to remove.
3. Set the window style with a call to `SetWindowLongPtr`.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Just found that all by myself. And it works well. ^^